# NSString regex for extracting negative numbers as part of an equation

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I'm trying to match a math equation using regex (in Objective-C on an iPhone app), and could use help in coming up with a regex which works for the second scenario listed below.

I've created the following Objective-C code to extract an equation of the form `(1÷4)` or `(-1÷4)` if there's a negative number ahead of a product or divider: (I include this here to help explain the question I'm trying to answer)

```
NSString* equation = @"1+(-1÷4)";
NSString* matcher = @"(-){0,1}(\\.|\\d)+(÷|×){1,}";
    NSRegularExpression *equation_regex = [NSRegularExpression  regularExpressionWithPattern:matcher options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    while([equation_regex numberOfMatchesInString:working_function options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [equation length])])
    {
    // regex finds '-1÷4'
}
```

However, this falls apart for the following equation: 3-1÷4 where -1 shouldn't be extracted since it's not part of the 1÷4 in the equation.

I've attempted to alter the regex (with my limited regex expertise!) to exlucde the -1 IFF there's a number ahead of the - via the following:

```
NSString* equation = @"3-1÷4";
NSString* matcher = @"((^\\d)(-)){0,1}(\\.|\\d)+(÷|×){1,}";
    NSRegularExpression *power_regex = [NSRegularExpression  regularExpressionWithPattern:power_regex_pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    while([power_regex numberOfMatchesInString:working_function options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [working_function length])])
    {

}
```

Where the regex `((^\\d)(-)){0,1}` is my attempt to only match the negative part if there's no leading digit on the - (i.e. `1÷4` and not `-1÷4`), which doesn't work, hence the question. I hope I've explained this sufficiently! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you didn't extend the formula with the number zero when you discover an orphan `-` operator, before you start to work out, i.e. `1+(-1÷4)` becomes `1+(0-1÷4)` and `3-1÷4` becomes `3-1÷4` (which is the same), and you won't have problem to create a common regular expression, and the final result has to be the same, because the leading zero won't change the formula.

Comment: Actually, @holex,  your suggestion lead to further thinking and a tweak in my code which solves the -1÷4, which was only equipped to manage **a number, a product, a number**. I've changed it to cope with **a product, a number, a product, a number**. This resolves the issue, but how do I close this question? I'm happy to keep it open, if someone can solve the original regex Q which would still be useful, and discuss a solution which might be useful for posterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid matching the `-` if it is preceded by a digit, you could use

```
"((?<!\\d)-)?[\\d.]+[÷×][\\d.]+"
```

The trailing `?` in `((?<!\\d)-)?` makes the `-` optional, and if it is present, the negative look-behind `(?<!\\d)` prevents a match if it is preceded by a digit.

`[\\d.]+` matches `0-9` or `.` one or more times.

Note, only tested using the `java.util.regex` class, although I think that the `NSRegularExpression` class is similar.

**Edit:**

I find it difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do, but if you are just trying to match a negative number if it is not preceded by a digit, you could use

```
"(?<!\\d)-\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"
```

Comment: This worked a treat. The final regex is `@"((?<!\\d)-)?(\\d)+(÷|×){1,}(\\d)+"`. This could probably do with simplifying, but it works none the less. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDunne. Note that `(÷|×){1,}` means 'one _or more_ of either `÷` or `×`'. If you just want one of either of those, use `[÷×]`, or `(÷|×)` if you want to capture it. If you are using the brackets to capture the numbers, then you need to use `(\\d+)` not `(\\d)+`. To capture the `-` for either number also, you could use `"((?:(?<!\\d)-)?\\d+)(÷|×)(-?\\d+)"`. That would produce three captures: the first number, the operator, and the second number.